# Consistency between OOB error rate and the confusion matrix

Tags: r, random-forest

When inspecting the statistics of my models, it looks like the numbers in the `confusion matrix` are not consistent with those of the `OOB error rate` in `randomForest`.

**How can I deduce the OOB error rate from the confusion matrix?** What is the relationship between them?

In the example below, I print the output from two models, one that was fit with stratified sampling (using a subset of the samples in `sampsize`) and one that was fit without (i.e. using the default sampling scheme, which I think uses all samples).

[image]

I don't have the data public, but here are the function calls:

```
sumY = summary(Y)
sampsize <- c(sumY["Y0"]/10, sumY["Y1"])

# First model in the image above
strat.rf.model <- randomForest(x=X,y=Y,sampsize=sampsize, strata=Y)

# Second model in the image above    
rf.model <- randomForest(x=X,y=Y)
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not inconsistent, it's just arithmetic:

```
> 180 / (1699 + 180)
[1] 0.09579564
> 63 / (63 + 58)
[1] 0.5206612
> (180 + 63) / (1699 + 180 + 63 + 58)
[1] 0.1215
```

The error rate in each class is defined as the proportion of misclassified observations in just that class, whereas the overall misclassification rate is the proportion of misclassified observations for the entire data set.

It is rare for the error rate for each class to exactly match the overall error rate. If you stop and think about it for a second, this makes perfect sense: some classes are going to be harder to identify than others, and then the overall error rate is sort of the "average".